# Is it bad to use a Windows Form as a Control?

Tags: .net, winforms

I know it's possible to use a `Form` as a child control in another Form.

```
ChildForm child = new ChildForm();
child.TopLevel = false;
child.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
child.Show();
containerControl.Controls.Add(child);
```

I realise this is not what a `Form` was designed for. I was wondering what the implications here are, as opposed to using a `UserControl`? Are there any real downsides? Any large, unnecessary overheads? Any unexpected behaviours?

On the other hand, are there any advantages of using a form? Is there anything you can't do with a UserControl that you can do with a form, which may be useful if used as a child control?

I understand that both `Form` and `UserControl` inherit `ContainerControl`, but how different do their non-inherited members make them?

**My scenario**

The reason I'm asking is because I have an existing `Form` control, that I'd *like* to be displayed on its own sometimes (for development and as a little extra feature), but it doesn't *need* to be. However, I do need the `Closing` event of the form (which is not inherited from `ContainerControl`) and I need to be able to cancel closing the form if a file has been edited and not saved.

I've also noticed in my findings that a `Form` seems to have some transparency options that a `UserControl` doesn't seem to have, but I'm not sure if these will work when the form is used as a child control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the Inheritance Hierarchy in MSDN you find out that both UserControl and Form inherit from [ContainerControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.aspx) so in fact up to their base class nearly everything should be the same.

said so, in general, *I think* you should avoid using a Form object hosted as a control unless you are dealing with legacy unchangeable code or unless you absolutely want this design so to be able, in certain other cases, to show the form all alone as top level non hosted anywhere.

If you simply need a container to put your other UI controls you can use a UserControl.

in fact everything down to the Win32 level translates to handles and message pumps / WindowProc etc, even a simple TextBox will have an handle and will receive and consume messages taking care of its client and non client area and so on.

Comment: I knew they both inherit `ContainerControl`, I'll update my question. The question is more 'why not?'. I've done a form, which doesn't *need* to be displayed on it's own, but it could be nice, however I do need the `Closing` event. I'll update my question to be a bit more specific to my scenario.

Comment: but then, if you really to show forms inside a form, why not the MDI approach so you simply have a main form with MDIParent set to True and when showing another form you set the MDIParent of child form as the main form? That is the natural way it was designed to work.

Comment: Well... the form I want to be the parent of this Form/Control is already and MDI child. Is this just too messy? Do you know of another way I can catch the Closing event?